# Jsoup не хочет парсить!

Tags: java, html, jsoup

Имеется такой html код:

```
<div class="adview_image__content">
        <img class="adview_image__base adview_image__base_type_visible adview_image__base_type_loaded" itemprop="image"src="http://content.kufar.by/pictures/64/6424370289.jpg" alt="2-Х КОМНАТНАЯ КВАРТИРА" data-src="http://content.kufar.by/pictures/64/6424370289.jpg" data-id="0">
        <i class="adview_image__zoom sprite_view_zoom_icon"></i>
 </div>
```

Надо спарсить картинку, никак не получается.
Пробовал парсить так, чтобы было видно передается ли вообще что-то :

```
imgUrl = document.select(".adview_image__base adview_image__base_type_visible adview_image__base_type_loaded").toString();
```

При выводе на экран ничего не появляется. В чем может быть дело!? Можно ли вообще с этого когда картинку спарсить с помощью Jsoup?

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в том, что в вашем запросе используются пробелы.

Попробуйте так:

```
document.select(".adview_image__base");
```

Если необходимо выбрать элемент с несколькими классами:

```
document.select(".adview_image__base.adview_image__base_type_visible");
```

Comment: Отлично! 
Первый вариант сработал!
Спасибо!